# Why script embed between other tags is executed before them?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm beginner in Javascript and I was reading [this](http://javascript.info/tutorial/adding-script-html). From what I know (and what is stated there) the page should render cascadingly, but when I run on Chrome this

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1>Counting rabbits</h1>
<script>
    for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
      alert("Rabbit "+i+" out of the hat!")
    }
  </script>
<h1>...Finished counting</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

the JS script is executed before the h1 tag appears. Why is that?

Comment: Ah, I see, there are two h1 tags

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I meant before the first one.

Comment: It's not guaranteed that the browser renders the page before showing the alert.

Comment: @JJJ Are alerts treated somehow differently than other scirpts?

Comment: No. The browser doesn't render the page before other lines in the script either.

Comment: @JJJ So why doesn't it display "Counting rabbits" before the alerts appear?

Comment: Because it's not guaranteed that the browser renders the page before showing the alert.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed a good observation [IFeel3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5562332/ifeel3).
I tried this out and was surprised too.

Firefox renders it just the way that the [article](http://javascript.info/tutorial/adding-script-html) mentions. 
Chrome keeps the rendering part for the end.
I went a bit further and modified your code to the following...

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1 id="1">Counting rabbits</h1>
    <script>
        alert(document.getElementById('1'));
        alert(document.getElementById('2'));
        for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
            alert("Rabbit "+i+" out of the hat!")
        }
  </script>
    <h1 id="2">...Finished counting</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

If we now run this in the browser, observe that the `h1` element with `id=1` exists in the DOM while the second `h1` element with `id=2` is `null` in the alert dialog (rightly so as the browser is yet to parse the second `h1` element).

So chrome seems to be parsing the document and loading the elements in DOM the right way. It only seems to be keeping the display part for the end.

The article also mentions that...moving the scripts towards the end of BODY has certain pros and cons

> **Good**, because user doesn’t have to wait for scripts.
>   **Bad**, because the functions become available after the HTML is loaded. A user has a chance to click on button which may not work.
>   Usually adding special code that hides functionality until the script
>   has loaded resolves the problem.

I guess its because of the con (the reason mentioned in the **Bad** section) that chrome seems to hold the elements in the DOM but not displaying them till the end when the entire page has loaded (so that user can't interact with the page before the javascript has loaded).

This is of course is my interpretation and may not be the actual reason. But I would be glad to know others opinions.